# maven assembly archive with leading ./ folder

Tags: maven, tar, maven-assembly-plugin

I’m using maven assembly plugin that creates a targz archive with this descriptor:

```
<assembly>
    <formats>
        <format>tar.gz</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>

    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <outputDirectory>./folder</outputDirectory>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/someFolder</directory>
            <fileMode>0755</fileMode>
            <directoryMode>0755</directoryMode>
            <lineEnding>lf</lineEnding>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.sh</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

In older builds I got archive that had leading ./ folder like:

```
tar –tf someArchive.tar.gz
./file1
./file2
```

But now I’m getting archive without leading dotslash folder.
How can I fix this problem and to create archive with leading ./ folder?

Also I investigated that tar works differently in two cases:

```
1. tar cvzf someArchive.tar.gz folder
```

In this way I get archive without leading ./ folder

```
2. tar cvzf someArchive.tar.gz ./folder
```

In this way archive starts with ./ folder

Comment: ./ is the same as without *./* furthermore an absolute path in tar archives will be cut.

Comment: Yes, but when I list archive with tar -tf, I get diffenent results

Comment: That's the only difference, but logical they are the same.